# "interactible" or "interactable"

Tags: nouns, orthography

I came across this when developing a computer system in an object-oriented way. That is grouping data and functionality which relate to each other into objects and give those objects names.

Now, currently, I work on the only a part of the system which provides mutable state in the form of objects one can interact with, in a domain-specific sense. I was about to call them `Interactables`, I realized, however, that this is not a well-defined word.

The question is, is there an alternative noun for *thing you interact with* in the english language. And if not, what would be the preferred way to spell this word: **Interactible** or **Interactable**?

Comment: "Interact" strictly means that you act on it and it acts on you; I think you just want a word for something you act on, which might be *object*.

Comment: yes, good point. With the actor being the subject. By now I found out about IEML in which subject and object are two of the 25 lowercase letters: https://intlekt.io/25-basic-categories/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two problems: *interactable* isn't a common word and if it were, it would be an adjective, not a noun.

Fortunately, the first problem is easily solved.

> **Interactive** adjective
>
> 1 : mutually or reciprocally active
>
> 2 : involving the actions or input of a user

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interactive

As to the second problem, *interactive* is certainly much more often an adjective, but you can find it used as a noun, especially, as [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interactive) says, as "a feature (as in a museum) that can be interacted with."

For example:

> Given how rapidly technology, delivery platforms, and interfaces are changing, it's not surprising that today's teens might find interactives in the museums outdated and pretty boring

[*Shivers Down Your Spine: Cinema, Museums, and the Immersive View*](https://books.google.com/books?id=T1CsAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=interactives&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwinzpqP-OXlAhWX4J4KHQB7DJQQ6AEwA3oECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=interactives&f=false)

> There has been a slow trickle of research...on the use-value of interactives within museum environments and art galleries.

[*Museums in the New Mediascape: Transmedia, Participation, Ethics*](https://books.google.com/books?id=OPHiBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA87&dq=interactives&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4kqSn9-XlAhVFuZ4KHYNHAZAQ6AEwB3oECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=interactives&f=false)

Those are clearly different uses than the one you're proposing, but they illustrate that the word's meaning is likely obvious enough that a new coinage will be easily understood.

Comment: Interesting, so it _interactives_ is probably better suited than _interactables_ then. Is there any word referring to the act of making a noun from an adjective? (for instance _it's interactive_ -> _all interactives_). I see this all the time in IT. A quick Google search, for example, points to [this article](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/adventure-game-phase-5-interactables?projectId=5c514af7edbc2a001fd5c012#) devoted to _Interactables_.

Comment: Well, actually there would be ambiguity between the singular of _interactives_ and the original adjective. It's quite hard to use it as a noun without a proper singular.

Comment: Or _interactors_ 

Comment: @BrunoZell, *interactive* would be the singular form of the noun.  My examples all used *interactives* because it's easier to search for, since you know it's a noun, while *interactive* would most likely be an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Google corrects "interactible" to "interactable", so to me, that's a definitive answer that it's spelled "Interactable" with an "a".</del>

Urban Dictionary has a definition for "Interactable" with an "a":
https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Interactable

> An object that you are able to interact with, to manipulate.

So although it's a user-defined word, it shows that there are people who use the word "interactable", which is enough to make it an official word, right?

But using that logic, you can find a lot of other people who use "interactible" with an "i", which makes that version also a word, and therefore also acceptable.

IMHO, I'd say the version with an "a" is better, because it contains the word "able", which is a key part of the meaning: "able to interacted with".

The word is "Interactable" with an "a".

Comment: Please explain your answer with more research.

Comment: For me Google corrects it to "intractable" which has another meaning.

Comment: @BrunoZell you're right. i didnt even notice that lol

Comment: << ... although it's a user-defined word, it shows that there are people who use the word "interactable", which is enough to make it an official word, right? >> No. the term 'non-word' exists to cover candidates that are not considered to have made it into the lexicon. There needs to be a reasonable level of use / understanding. Two schoolchildren may come up with say 'pargyano' but their using and understanding it doesn't confer wordness.

Answer (score 0):

I can find references to both interactible and interactble used as nouns to talk about objects in video games; however, "interactable" with an "a" appears to be more common.

For interactable:

- [Fandom page about Interactables in Risk of Rain 2](https://riskofrain2.fandom.com/wiki/Interactables)
- [Official tutorial video about Interactables in Unity VR Toolkit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFHLwsjT9jI&ab_channel=VirtualRealityToolkit)
- [GameRant article about Interactables in Diablo 4](https://gamerant.com/diablo-4-highlight-interactables/)
- [Documentation about Interactables in Spatial IO](https://docs.spatial.io/interactable)

For interactible:

- [Fandom page about Interactibles in The Evil Within](https://theevilwithin.fandom.com/wiki/Interactibles)
- [Game Design online course with a series on Interactibles](https://www.sovereignmoon.studio/learn/course/game-development-course/)
- [Documentation about Interactibles in VRE for Unreal Engine](https://vreue4.com/documentation?section=replicating-interactibles)